# Compute Engine VM not responding to request

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, syncthing

I am having trouble accessing a port on my vm. As you can see from a netstat command, port 8384 is open and listening for tcp connections. I also have a picture of the firewall rules saying the port 8384 allow to have connections from anywhere. Of course, I am typing into my browser http://[external-ip-adddress]:8384. I am not sure where to go from here in order to trouble shoot the issue.

[image: picture of open ports on computer]
[image: firewall rule saying that port 8384 is open]

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 represents the localhost. In to allow the port to be broadcasted to the internet, it has to be one can provide the external ip address or 0.0.0.0. In syncthing you can change the port `./syncthing -gui-address=0.0.0.0:8384`